# Why MorphiaIterator can be iterated only once?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm using Morphia 0.107.

Why is MorphiaIterator class built in a way that it can be iterated only once?

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia;
import org.mongodb.morphia.query.Query;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        Morphia m = new Morphia();
        Datastore ds = m.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "test");

        Query<Person> q = ds.createQuery(Person.class);

        // MorphiaIterator
        Iterable<Person> iterable = q.fetchEmptyEntities();
        System.out.println(iterable.iterator().hasNext());
        for (Person person : iterable) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }

        System.out.println(iterable.iterator().hasNext());
        for (Person person : iterable) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }

        // This should work, but throws java.util.NoSuchElementException
        ds.delete(Person.class, q.fetchKeys());

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException. 
It will be thrown because underlying methods first iterate through the MorphiaIterator and then try to call its iterator().next().